# Pytest - How to parametrize with different test data with different params send to fixture?

Tags: python, pytest

I was working on the pyTest. So here's the case, the same pyTest has multiple test data, however, different test data have different settings in the fixture. I look through the documentation of pyTest and figure out doing both independently using `parametrized` function as below:

For data-driven test data:
`@pytest.mark.parametrize('valid_data', test_data, ids=test_data_ids)`
In this case where `test_data` is a json file that has about 6 different test data and `test_data_ids` is the list of the test data ids.

Then for passing parameters to fixture:
`@pytest.mark.parametrize('setup_person', [['student']], indirect=True)`. In this case `setup_person` is my fixture name, `student` is one of the parameters accepted by the fixture.

However now I need them both combined to works, I can't find any docs or resources about this. What I want to achieve is data-driven testing while sending different params to fixture. Here is my fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=['student', 'teacher', 'outsider'])
def setup_person(request):
    if request.param is 'student':
        setup = 'This is student.'
    elif request.param is 'teacher':
        setup = 'This is teacher.'
    elif request.param is 'outsider':
        setup = 'This is outsider'
    else:
        setup = 'Incorrect parameter passed'
    return setup
```

This is a simple example of what my fixture looks like, as you can see I have 3 parameters in the fixture and each will return different things to the test.

This is what my test looks like:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('setup_person', [['student']], indirect=True)
@pytest.mark.parametrize('valid_data', test_data, ids=test_data_ids)
def test_person(setup_person, valid_data):
    response = setup_person
    assert response == 'This is student.'
```

However when I tried to combine both parametrized functions, it seems that the parameter `student` will only be passed once when the first parametrize is running, then the second parametrize with the test data will not passing the `student` and fixture will not be saved that as well.

So when I run the test, it results in always going to the `else` part because nothing has been passed when I run my test data parametrized function.

Is there any other way that I can combine both functions together or there is another workaround for this? Thank you for reading and I appreciate any helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you simply made a mistake in the first `@pytest.mark.parametrize` decorator by using a list within a list. A simple list like this:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize('setup_person', ['student'], indirect=True)
@pytest.mark.parametrize('valid_data', test_data, ids=test_data_ids)
```

...should produce every possible combination of values from the first `parametrize` decorator (in this case `student` would be always passed to the fixture function) and from the second `parametrize` decorator which means whatever `test_data` contains.

Comment: I've changed to simple list however the problem remain the same. I've printed out what request.param is, it is `student` so up to here is correct. However reaching the if-else statement it always goes to the else statement as if request.param had nothing already.

Comment: Hey sorry it was my mistake on this one! I've changed some value in the fixture and I forgot to changed to back, now it works like a charm! Thank you so much!

Comment: what would be the correct approach if the content of the list is generated in a previous test?

Comment: @Bored002 The correct approach would be **not** to have a test generate anything for other tests. You should either have a helper function or a fixture generate things for your tests.

Comment: Yes i agree but , the issue i'm facing with is that test_a is reading content from file and validating that content. and then test_B needs to test that content , which is a list of values i need to iterate over and perform a test on each one (Test_B). which is what i'm trying to solve with paramterize fixture

Comment: @Bored002 I suggest you post a new question for that. This beyond what the comments are for.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this class:

```
class parameterized:
    '''
    Use this decorator on test methods like this:
    @parameterized(actual=[5,6],expected=[5,6])
    def test3(self, actual, expected):
        self.shouldEqual(actual,expected)

    The example uses parameters actual and expected, but they can be anything you like, as long
    as the parameters match in number and name.
    This decorator uses unittest.TestCase.subTest to separately markup every failing test.
    '''
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __call__(self, fn):
        def test_wrapped(itself):
            size = len(self.kwargs[list(self.kwargs.keys())[0]])
            for index in range(size):
                test_method_parameters = {k: self.kwargs[k][index] for k in self.kwargs}
                with itself.subTest(**test_method_parameters):
                    fn(itself, **test_method_parameters)

        return test_wrapped
```

I use it in conjunction with `unittest`, so I'm not certain that it will work with `pytest` due to its use of `subTest`.

Source: https://bitbucket.org/teamqu/qutest/src/default/Test.py

Comment: Hmm ok I'll try out this one to see whether it works with pyTest or not. Thanks!